# Are star stickers mutar?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, astronomy, art

Do any contemporary *poskim* discuss the usage of star stickers with regard to the prohibition of depicting celestial bodies (e.g. the glow-in-the-dark ones people put on walls and ceilings)? What if they are affixed without representing a constellation, but such that they do end up recreating an image of a night sky? Is affixing a sticker akin to drawing a star?

Comment: The shapes are called "stars" but they don't actually resemble the stars in the sky. That may well make a difference.

Comment: If you like an answer consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying which additional information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the prohibition in question would be "You shall not make for yourself a carved item or any image which is in the heaven above..." (Exodus 20:4).

- Rambam implies that the prohibition is only in constructing an image in order to worship it. (Sefer Hamitzvos negative commandment #2) Assuming you have no idolatrous intent it ought to be permitted.

> שהזהירנו מעשות ע''ז לזולתנו **כדי שיעבוד אותה**

- Chinuch (neg. 27) seems to say that the matter is a dispute between Rambam (prohibited only to worship) and Ramban (always prohibited).

Comment: You also have to ask yourself whether sticky "stars" are actually images of the stars in the sky or they are just given the same name. Are they also called "kochavim" in Hebrew?